# getting error echoing javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, echo

Im getting an error that there is a syntax problem on the line where `selection = ui.item.addClass` etc.. , but I can't figure out what it is. I think I have escaped all the right quotes but I'm not sure. note: the first two variables are meant to contain empty single quotes.

```
<?php      
echo    "<script>";

echo    "$(function(){";


echo  "var selection = \' \'; ";

echo  "var selectClass = \' \'; ";

echo  " $(\".menu\").menu({ ";

echo  " select: function (event, ui) { "
echo   " $(\'.selected\', this).removeClass(\'selected\'); ";
echo     "  selection = ui.item.addClass(\'selected\').children(\'a\').attr(\'name\');";


echo  " }"; // closes select function

echo  "  }); "; // closes menu
echo  " </script>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the point in the javascript output being `echo ;`? Why don't you just drop out of your PHP tags then drop back in?

Comment: you dont need to escape `'` within a `"` - a plain 'select' would work

Comment: better yet why are you mixing javascript with php? separate the logic

Comment: This is just something I'm trying out. I'm not sure if I will keep it, but right now mixing javascript and php is the best way I know how to get a javascript variable to another page within all the other code I'm using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I shall simplify your code:

```
<?php      
echo  <<<'SCRIPT'
<script>
$(function(){
    var selection = ' ';
    var selectClass = ' ';
    $(".menu").menu({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
            selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').children('a').attr('name');
        } // closes select function
    }); // closes menu
}); // close function()
</script>
SCRIPT;
?>
```

You will find this "magically" fixes your problem because now you don't have the missing semicolon ;)

Answer (score 4):

Personally. I'd drop out of the tags for my Javascript.. When I have finished typing, I see no harm in re-opening PHP tags to continue..

```
 //Other code here 
?>
<script>
$(function(){


var selection = ' ';

var selectClass = ' ';

$(".menu").menu({

select: function (event, ui) { 
$('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').children('a').attr('name');


}// closes select function

});// closes menu
});// closes function()
</script>

<?php 
// Continue here 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon in line #14

```
echo  " select: function (event, ui) { ";
echo   " $(\'.selected\', this).removeClass(\'selected\'); ";
```

Fixing which gives this: http://eval.in/15236

```
<script>$(function(){var selection = \' \'; var selectClass = \' \';  $(".menu").menu({  select: function (event, ui) {  $(\'.selected\', this).removeClass(\'selected\');   selection = ui.item.addClass(\'selected\').children(\'a\').attr(\'name\'); }  });  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in last line add this

```
echo  "  }); "; // closes menu
// --- add this
echo " });";
// -----
echo  " </script>";
```

try it :D